# Can't see a source view controller after a modal segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a simple "present modally" segue on a button click and what I want is my source view controller to pop out a little on top. But as soon as segue animation ends, source view controller disappears. Is it a normal segue behaviour and I need to make animation myself or is there something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the modal presentation style for the modal to be "Over Full Screen" or "Over CurrentContext" instead of "Full Screen".

Comment: That solved my issue, thx a lot, but now after
transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled) when dismissing modal vc my source vc doesn't appear back. I have an interactive dismissal, mb I should dig into that

Comment: @ArtemMisesin Are you using a custom transition?  You may need to add the source view controller's view into the container view when your transition starts.  Also make sure you are calling `completeTransition:` at the end.  

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH16-SW10

Comment: Could you, please, be more specific about the container view?

Comment: http://d.pr/i/AeNc8

- and -

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning/1622045-containerview